# Google calendar API returns Unauthorized

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I have a calendar client I build like this

```
public static Calendar getCalendar(Credential credentials) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        return new Calendar.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JSON_FACTORY, credentials)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }
```

`calendar.events().list("primary").execute()` works and returns resuults

But this one complains 401: Unauthorized

```
  public static String subscirbeToHook(Credential user, Calendar service) throws IOException {

        Channel content = new Channel()
                .setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .setType("web_hook")
                .setResourceUri("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/watch")
                .setAddress("https://2e8e18e3.ngrok.io/");


        Channel channel = service.events()
                .watch("primary", content)
                .execute();


        return channel.getResourceId();
    }
```

I requested for `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` scope. I am lost. I tried different combination for the resource uri

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't do changes for the `resourceURI` because it's not currently supported in [Calendar Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push).

> Currently, the Google Calendar API supports notifications for changes
>   to the Acl, CalendarList, Events, and Settings resources.

These are the supported [Events resources](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch) request body:

```
{
  "id": string,
  "token": string,
  "type": string,
  "address": string,
  "params": {
    "ttl": string
  }
}
```

If successful, this method returns a response body with the following structure:

```
{
  "kind": "api#channel",
  "id": string,
  "resourceId": string,
  "resourceUri": string,
  "token": string,
  "expiration": long
}
```

Comment: I'm watching for events, which is supported

Comment: I have edited the answer. It is also same with events. The body request is same with Settings resources.